# That forbidden salute

Tags: english-to-german, word-order

Why is it *Sieg Heil*, with the word for *victory* coming before the word for *hail*? Why isn't it Hail Victory?

Answer (score 2):

["X Heil" has historically been used in various different greetings like "Petri Heil" among fishermen or "Gut Heil" among gymnasts.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heil#Jagd_und_Sport)

It is a greeting to wish "Heil" among the other person. In case of the Nazi greeting it's used to wish the blessing of victory on the other person.

It is not used to bless the victory itself, which is what "Heil Sieg" conveys.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I don't why people disliked my question, as if understanding the syntax of a nazi salute would be as bad as nazism itself.